# exclude meta(__type, symbol) info from graphql queries

Tags: graphql

When querying with Graphql, I get the following query.

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "type":"FeatureCollection",
      "features":[  
         {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "geometry":{  
               "type":"Point",
               "coordinates":[  
                  38.544907,
                  -121.740517
               ],
               "__typename":"GeometryType"
            },
            "__typename":"MapInfoType"
         }
      ]
   },
   "type":"geojson"
}
```

Is there a way in GraphQL to exclude all the meta information directly **without using external functions** to clean up the data?

What I want directly from GraphQL:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "type":"FeatureCollection",
      "features":[  
         {  
            "type":"Feature",
            "geometry":{  
               "type":"Point",
               "coordinates":[  
                  38.544907,
                  -121.740517
               ],
            },
         }
      ]
   },
   "type":"geojson"
}
```

and the query

import gql from "graphql-tag";

```
export default gql`
    {
        geoSites {

            mapInfo {
                type
                geometry {
                    type
                    coordinates
                }

            }
        }
    }
`;
```

Comment: Can you provide the query you're using?

Comment: @MarcoDaniels any query I send come with `__type` meta, but I did edit